# How can I capture a rectangular area from an image?

Tags: image-processing, image

I am looking for a method to extract rectangular areas from an image. The image is divided up into rectangular problem spaces like the image shown below. Each numbered problem is given with some text and some graphics.

---

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

I tried to use `ImageCorners`, `FindClusters` but they did not work.

```
img = Import["http://i.imgur.com/hcQZ85F.jpg"];
pts = ImageCorners[img, 5, 0.01];
HighlightImage[img, pts];
ListPlot[FindClusters[pts], AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

This is my bad result.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The result I want is would look like this, but I don't know how to get it.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Could you please elaborate this problem a little bit further. Right now I cannot really see what the characteristic elements that make up your regions are because your desired output is from a different page than the input example.

Comment: @Wizard These text are written by Korean language. but the text is just an image. I want to find the region coordinates around  text retangular using the numbered problem or others with image processing skill.

Comment: I would definitely analyse the image for whitespace between the different regions you want to extract or find some other characteristic elements in your image to look out for. Once those are found it should be a simple `ImageTake` on the remaining bounding box.

Comment: @Wizard yes I would like to find the coordinate for the `ImageTake` automatically using image processing skill because the pages are thousand.

Comment: it seems to me doing text recognition on the problem numbers would be helpfull

Comment: @JunhoLee: I get that, I just meant to think about what exactly separates one element you want from another (it seems to me that almost white lines in the image might already do the trick) and then detect those characteristic elements automatically. Afterwards it is just extraction with `ImageTake` and proper coordinates from the detection procedure mentioned before.

Comment: `ComponentMeasurements` or `SelectComponents` with property `"Rectangularity"` may be of interest, as well as the "embedding" properties.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Tricky.

But with a bit of creative cheating, I can get close:

First, load the image and binarize it:

```
img = Import["http://i.imgur.com/qAZBdFb.jpg"];    
bin = MorphologicalBinarize[ColorNegate@img, {.1, .5}]
```

[image]

I invert the image for two reasons: First, `MorphologicalBinarize` takes a lower and an upper threshold, i.e. it assumes bright blobs on dark background. Second, the next function `ComponentMeasurements` looks for connected bright components:

```
comp = ComponentMeasurements[
   bin, {"Centroid", "ConvexVertices", "ConvexArea", 
    "EnclosingComponentCount"}, #3 < 10000 && #4 == 0 &];
```

This is the "cheating" part I've mentioned above: I can't separate the two "boxes" labeled "04" and "05" cleanly from the other components, because the boxes are closer to the blocks below them than some of the answers. So I cheated by removing the boxes: I ignore components that have a convex hull area > 10000 (the boxes) or are enclosed by another component (the stuff inside the boxes).

Next, I calculate the distances between all the components:

```
points = comp[[All, 2, 1]];
convexHulls = comp[[All, 2, 2]];
```

My first try was to use the centroid distance. Very cheap to calculate, but it "penalizes" large components:

```
(*distances = Outer[EuclideanDistance, points, points, 1];*)
```

So instead, I calculate the distances between the convex hulls of each pair of components:

```
convexHullDist = 
  Map[Function[hull, 
    With[{nf = Nearest[hull]}, Norm[nf[#][[1]] - #] &]], convexHulls];
distances = Outer[Min[#1 /@ #2] &, convexHullDist, convexHulls, 1];
```

...convert that distance matrix to a graph:

```
g = WeightedAdjacencyGraph[distances];
```

...and find the minimal spanning tree for that distance graph:

```
spanningTree = 
 FindSpanningTree[g, VertexCoordinates -> points, EdgeStyle -> Red]

Show[
 img,
 spanningTree,
 Graphics[{Red, Point[points]}]
 ]
```

[image]

As expected, the minimum spanning tree has most of its edges inside each "box", and few links between boxes.

Here's a plot of the edge lengths in the spanning tree:

```
maxDistances = 
  Sort[distances[[#[[1]], #[[2]]]] & /@ EdgeList[spanningTree]];    
threshold = Mean[maxDistances[[{-7, -6}]]];    
ListPlot[maxDistances, PlotRange -> All, 
 GridLines -> {{}, {threshold}}]
```

[image]

The obvious idea is now to remove the longest edges from this graph:

```
splitGraph = 
 EdgeDelete[spanningTree, i_ <-> j_ /; distances[[i, j]] > threshold]
```

[image]

This looks promising. Let's draw the bounding rectangles for each of the connected components in this graph:

```
Show[img,
 splitGraph,
 Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Red}], Transparent, 
   Rectangle @@ 
      Transpose[MinMax /@ Transpose[Flatten[convexHulls[[#]], 1]]] & /@
     ConnectedComponents[splitGraph]}]]
```

[image]

And let's extract the image areas:

```
Multicolumn[
 Framed[ImageTrim[img, Flatten[convexHulls[[#]], 1]]] & /@ 
  ConnectedComponents[splitGraph]]
```

[image]

Close. The 7/5-component (I'm guessing this is a multiple choice answer?) is farther from the box it belongs to than the distance between some of the other blocks.

If you want to get better results for this specific layout, you could probably split the image into columns first, then process each column separately and look for good "row dividers". This is much simpler, because you have two 1d problems instead of one 2d problem. But I like the spanning tree approach better, because it makes fewer assumptions about the layout. For example, it should work for column-major, chessboard or hexagonal layouts just as well.

---

**ADD:**

For completeness sake (and because I was curious), here's the simpler way to do it mentioned in the last paragraph:

```
imgGrey = ColorConvert[img, "Grayscale"];
```

Take the columnwise mean of the image grey values, and look for extended peaks in that profile:

```
peaksX = Round@FindPeaks[Mean[ImageData[imgGrey]], 25][[All, 1]];
ListLinePlot[Mean[ImageData[imgGrey]], PlotRange -> All, 
 GridLines -> {peaksX, {}}]
```

[image]

Then, do more or less the same for the row-wise mean for each column:

```
Flatten[Function[xRange,
    column = ImageTake[imgGrey, All, xRange];
    peaksY = 
     Round@FindPeaks[Mean /@ ImageData[Opening[column, 5]], 20][[All, 
       1]];
    Framed[Image[ImageTake[column, #], ImageSize -> All]] & /@ 
     Partition[peaksY, 2, 1]] /@ 
   Partition[peaksX, 2, 1]] // Multicolumn
```

[image]

Quick and dirty. No idea how well this would work for different images.

Comment: Great thanks a lot. Your discription is a my first guide for the study of   image processing.

Answer (score 6):

```
img = Import["http://i.imgur.com/qAZBdFb.jpg"];
bin = MorphologicalBinarize[ColorNegate@img, {.1, .5}]
```

[image]

```
closbin = FillingTransform[Closing[bin, {Array[1 &, 10]}]]
```

[image]

```
twolargerbox = 
 TakeLargestBy[
   Values@ComponentMeasurements[closbin, {"Count", "BoundingBox"}], 
   First, 2][[All, -1]]
```

> {{{196., 265.}, {375., 389.}}, {{6., 265.}, {183., 370.}}}

```
twolargercom = ImageTrim[img, #] & /@ twolargerbox
```

[image]

```
smallcombox = 
 MorphologicalTransform[
  Closing[MorphologicalTransform[
    ImageSubtract[closbin, SelectComponents[closbin, "Count", -2]], 
    "BoundingBoxes", Infinity], 7], "BoundingBoxes", Infinity]
```

[image]

```
smallcomcom = 
 ImageTrim[img, #] & /@ 
  Values@ComponentMeasurements[smallcom, "BoundingBox"]
```

[image]

```
Multicolumn[Flatten[{twolargercom, smallcomcom}], 2, Frame -> All, 
 FrameStyle -> Red, Alignment -> {Center, Center}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A improved version based on *Graph Theory* and *cluster*:

Get a binarize image firstly by nike's [method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/91727/21532)

```
img = Import["http://i.imgur.com/qAZBdFb.jpg"];
bin = MorphologicalBinarize[ColorNegate@img, {.1, .5}]
```

[image]

Create a graph use `NearestNeighborGraph`,I find $2$ nearest vertices for every vertex here:

```
com = ComponentMeasurements[bin, "Centroid"];
g = NearestNeighborGraph[Values[com], 2]
```

[image]

Connect those connected commponent by shortest line(long of edge).

```
ConnectSeparateGraph[graph_] := 
 Module[{rule, pts, f, var1, var2, nearePoint, completeGraph}, 
  rule = Dispatch[
    MapThread[Rule, {VertexList[graph], GraphEmbedding[graph]}]];
  pts = WeaklyConnectedComponents[graph] /. rule;
  f = Nearest /@ Most[pts];
  var2 = Drop[pts, #] & /@ Range[Length[pts] - 1];
  var1 = MapThread[Catenate /@ # /@ #2 &, {f, var2}];
  nearePoint = 
   Catenate[
    Map[First[MinimalBy[#, EuclideanDistance @@ # &]] &, 
     Flatten[{var1, var2}, List /@ {2, 3, 4, 1, 5}], {2}]];
  completeGraph = 
   CompleteGraph[Length[pts], 
    EdgeWeight -> EuclideanDistance @@@ nearePoint];
  EdgeAdd[graph, 
   UndirectedEdge @@@ (nearePoint[[EdgeIndex[completeGraph, #] & /@ 
         EdgeList[FindSpanningTree[completeGraph]]]] /. 
      Reverse /@ Normal[rule])]]
graph = ConnectSeparateGraph[g]
```

[image]

Set a weight for every edges

```
weightGraph = 
 Graph[graph, 
  EdgeWeight -> 
   Thread[EdgeList[graph] -> EuclideanDistance @@@ (EdgeList[graph])]];
```

Find $8$ clusters for the graph and show the partition effect

```
clusters = 
  FindClusters[VertexList[weightGraph], 8, 
   DistanceFunction -> (EuclideanDistance[#1, #2] + 
       GraphDistance[weightGraph, #, #2] + 
       If[VertexConnectivity[weightGraph, #, #2] == 1, 
        EuclideanDistance[#1, #2], 0.] &), Method -> "KMedoids"];
Graph[weightGraph, 
 VertexStyle -> 
  Catenate[Thread /@ Tuples[clusters -> {Unevaluated@RandomColor[]}]],
  VertexSize -> {"Scaled", 0.02}]
```

[image]

Creating a connected binarize image based on the cluster you have partitioned

```
{show, conBin} = 
  MapThread[
   Function[{image, color}, 
    Show[image, 
     Subgraph[weightGraph, #, VertexCoordinates -> #, 
        BaseStyle -> Directive[Thick, color]] & /@ clusters]], {{img, 
     bin}, {Unevaluated[RandomColor[]], White}}];show
```

[image]

Find *BoundingBox* for every component,and trim out of the *rectangle* from your original image

```
Style[Multicolumn[
  ImageTrim[img, #] & /@ 
   Values[ComponentMeasurements[conBin, "BoundingBox"]], 2, 
  Frame -> All, ItemSize -> All, FrameStyle -> Red], 
 ImageSizeMultipliers -> {1}]
```

[image]