# How to detect rectangles with certain colors in an image?

Tags: image-processing, image, computer-vision

I'd like to find the red bordered rectangles in this image:

[image]

Here are my example images:

```
examples = CloudGet @ "https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/cb4a73b7-5108-4c46-985c-769aa1eef3aa";
```

It’s tricky because they can be nested. There are at least seven of them in the above image, my current code only detects one of them so far:

```
img = examples[[3]];
mf1 = MeanFilter[img, 5];
ht1 = HistogramTransform[mf1];
i = SelectComponents[SelectComponents[Binarize[ht1, .2], Small], Large];
bb = Last /@ ComponentMeasurements[i, "BoundingBox"] // First;
bbc = Mean /@ bb;
Show[i, Graphics[{Red, Opacity[0.5], Rectangle[bb[[1]], bb[[2]]]}]]
```

[image]

**Related Questions:**

- [How can I detect a rectangular region of interest in a picture?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21059/how-can-i-detect-a-rectangular-region-of-interest-in-a-picture)
- [Detecting rectangle shape from an image](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109977/detecting-rectangle-shape-from-an-image)
- [How can I capture a rectangular area from an image?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91697/how-can-i-capture-a-rectangular-area-from-an-image)

Comment: Embedding and `"Rectangularity"` properties from `SelectComponents` or `ComponentMeasurements` may be of interest

Answer (score 7):

Here's my take at the issue (some comments are inlined)

```
extractRectangles[i_Image?ImageQ] :=
Block[
    {dims, i0, i1, masks1, masks2, masks3, tfun, coords},
    (* downsampling (just to make it faster) *) 
    i0 = ImageResize[RemoveAlphaChannel[i], 500];
    dims = ImageDimensions[i0];
    (* smoothing *)
    i1 = MeanShiftFilter[i0, 3, .05, MaxIterations->5];
    (* color based segmentation *)
    masks1 = DominantColors[i1, All, "CoverageImage",
        MinColorDistance -> .02,
        ColorCoverage -> .02
    ];
    (* mask cleaning *)
    masks2 = FillingTransform @ Opening[#,2] & /@ masks1;
    (* mask selection *)
    masks3 = Flatten[Map[
        Values@ComponentMeasurements[
            #, "BoundingBox",
            And[#Rectangularity > .5, #Area > .005 Times @@ dims] &
        ]&, masks2], 1];

    (* scaling to the original image size *)
    tfun = ScalingTransform[ImageDimensions[i] / dims];
    coords = tfun /@ masks3;
    (* rectangles *)
    Rectangle @@@ coords
]
```

Compared to your attempt I used a `MeanShiftFilter` in place of the `MeanFilter` to better preserve the hard edges and `DominantColors` to get a more controlled colour segmentation.

Once that's done I want to have just one more utility to get consistent colouring for the rectangles

```
exprColor[expr_] := 
 RGBColor["#" <> IntegerString[Hash[Unevaluated[expr]], 16, 6]]
```

And now this is the result.

```
res = extractRectangles /@ examples;

MapThread[
 Function[{image, rectangles}, 
  HighlightImage[
   image, {{"Boundary", 10}, exprColor[#], #} & /@ rectangles, 
   ImageSize -> 400]
  ],
 {examples, res}
 ] // Column
```

[image]

The main issues I have still are:

- it gets thrown off by the text and thus some rectangles are smaller than they should be
- it does not deals very well with nested rectangles
- it has no notion of overlapping rectangles

Unfortunately, I don't have much time to dig into this more in depth.

Cheers!